# Uninstalling Lenovo Vantage & Understanding Denied Permissions

Tags: windows-10

I have a Lenovo laptop and it had Lenovo Vantage installed. I attempted to uninstall it using Windows’ “Apps & features”, but it couldn’t locate the uninstaller’s .exe. Nagigation to said .exe and attempting to run it would do nothing as far as I can tell. So I manually deleted the Lenovo folder within the "Program Files (x86)" Windows directory. After that I attempted to delete the Lenovo folder within the `C:\ProgramData` directory, but got permission denied.

I tried opening the folder but was also being denied permissions to do so, so I changed the owner to myself.

[image]
[image]

The files causing the permission issues are within the `C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\Vantage\SystemData\Vaul` directory and are called `UPEAPIKey` and `UPEUserID`. I tried searching for them online but there are exactly [zero results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxRI.jpg). I also cannot open them after having changed the owner, getting an error "ERROR Can not open file (...)".

[image]

I also can't copy or move the files.

[image]

So my questions are, what could these files be, and how would I go about attempting to read their contents?

Comment: I attempted to uninstall it using Windows’ “Apps & features”, but it couldn’t locate the uninstaller’s .exe. ....   So I manually deleted the Lenovo folder within the "Program Files (x86)" Windows directory.      ......   Something has gone very wrong. Vantage is easy to uninstall.  I suggest trying a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link and Keep Everything to start.   ......https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John I have already performed a clean installation of Windows because of this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason that you can't open, move, or delete the files is because there's a running program that has them open with exclusive access. Exclusive access (which is the default on Windows, incidentally) prevents any other process from opening the file with more than the most minimal of privileges (enough to get basic metadata, and to tell when it changes or becomes available). It doesn't matter at all what the relative privilege levels of the two processes are; the lowliest sandboxed process could have a `HANDLE` open to a file that prevents even the SYSTEM account from doing anything significant with it.

To tell what process is holding a lock on the file (or on a registry key, pipe, etc.), you can use any of the tools for enumerating open HANDLEs on Windows. One that's built into the operating system is a GUI app called "Resource Monitor" (`%windir%\system32\perfmon.exe /res` or just `resmon`); go to the "CPU" tab, click in the "Search Handles" box in the header of the "Associated Handles" section, and type the file name (it does a full path search, so part of the name is file; no need for a complete path unless it's a common name). It will show you all the processes which have a HANDLE open to something with that name, and the path of the open HANDLE. Obviously, once you have the process(es) identified, you can kill it/them (if you have the permissions). That will forcibly free all of the process' HANDLEs and make the file(s) available again. Mind you, just because the file isn't locked doesn't mean you are guaranteed access, even as Administrator; a file can specifically deny Administrator (or the Administrators group) access to itself (in which case you need to forcibly overwrite the ACL, usually by taking ownership first). Worse, a file can be encrypted using Windows' Encrypting File System (EFS). To read or modify a file encrypted with EFS, you need one of the keys that the file is encrypted to, which is generally one per-user key for each authorized reader of the file. The per-user keys are themselves encrypted with a key derived from the user's password. This is built-in Windows security functionality, and completely transparent to the user (that is, the key is selected and unwrapped automatically if possible).

Beyond that, there are various options for reading or manipulating files that the OS doesn't let you touch. You can boot Windows in Safe Mode, or to the pre-installation environment (PE) or Recovery Environment (RE); in each of these cases there is a Windows OS running, but it has minimal processes or services running (in Safe Mode) or is running from a totally different installation (in PE or RE). PE is generally on Windows installation media and reached by booting from such external media; RE is generally on a hidden partition of your hard disk and accessed from the advance boot options menu (as is Safe Mode). Note that PE may not be able to open EFS-encrypted files, as it doesn't use the same users as the running system (Safe Mode does though, and RE can access the key files if you have the password). You could also try removing the drive and connecting it to another computer (where you have Administrator access), though that won't work for encrypted files.

Alternatively, you can boot to a non-Windows OS entirely. Linux is perfectly capable of reading (and generally writing) NTFS - the Windows file system - so you can use a Linux "Live" CD/DVD/flashdrive, or connect the drive to a machine running Linux, and mount the Windows (NTFS) partition to read it. Linux doesn't really know or care about NTFS ACLs, and doesn't do exclusive file access (nor would any process be holding the file open unexpectedly anyhow), so you should have full access from there... unless the file, or entire volume, is encrypted. If the volume is encrypted with Bitlocker, you'll need one of the Linux drivers that can read Bitlocker volumes (plus the Bitlocker recovery password or similar way to get the decryption key). If the file is encrypted with EFS... there *might* be a Linux tool to extract the encryption metadata, find the relevant per-user keys, get the password needed to unwrap (decrypt) the key, and use it, but I've never seen one personally.

Comment: At the time I used PowerToys' [File Locksmith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith) utility and it was free as far as it could tell. I appreciate your answer, I will try those methods to open the files.